# How to set up dynamic date cards

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I'm working on a project and there's this last small thing I need to figure out.

I have a waterfall graph, and I'm overlaying some cards on the x axis to display start and end date rather than the default values (the dates in the waterfall below are cards).

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRtTk.png)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXMPw.png)

I have a date slicer, and what I'm trying to do is tie the left card to the start date. I want it to show the first of the month if the first of the month is selected but show the first of the next month if anything else is selected. The problem I'm having is that in order for this waterfall to work, my calendar table needs to be set up quarterly, see below.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdKK8.png)

Therefore, the card is automatically going to the end of each quarter, no matter what I do. What's the best way to accomplish this?

I've tried using functions to change the display month, but the problem is, there is no consistent st5andard I can set looking at the end of quarter. I need the card to tie to the date on the slicer rather than the end of quarter date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this as a new measure for the left tile

```
Start Date Tile = 
  var startD = MIN('TheSlicerDateTable'[TheSlicerDateColumn])
  return IF(
    DAY(startD) = 1,
    startD,
    DATE( YEAR(startD), MONTH(startD) + 1, 1 )
  )
```

The above will work so long as the dates used by slicer are continuous.

Comment: I tried this, but the issue is that since my dates are only displaying the end of quarter, I'm essentially getting the first day of the month in the next quarter. For example, the start date set in the slicer is 7/31/2023. The card spits out 10/31/2023, because that's the closest date in my table.

Comment: The above answer isn't looking at your calendar table so the quarter dates issue shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: The calendar table is what the slicer dates are tied to.

Comment: If the slicer is set to: "7/31/2023" then `var startD` should also equal "7/31/2023". Ensure you have updated `var startD` to be the same column as the slicer is using.

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding. If the slicer is set to "7/31/2023", what do you want the tile to show?

Comment: I want it to show 8/1/2023 if the slicer is set to 7/31/2023. However, right now when the slicer is set to 7/21/2023, the card is showing 9/31/2023 (end of quarter). So your measure just made it show 10/1/2023 instead.

Comment: So do me a favour, try the "test" measure above (answer updated), and let me know what you get please.

Comment: The test measure returned 10/1/2023

Comment: Great, and now can you test these other two (updated in the answer) and let me know what you get when you're slicer is set to 7/31/2023.

Comment: I'm getting 9/30/2023 for both of them.

Comment: okay, I'm getting an idea of the problem. How is your calendar table created or where is it coming from?

Comment: I have a regular calendar table, but all the extra dates were messing up my waterfall table, so created a summarized table for the slicer that just pulled in the end of quarter. It won't let me send pictures through comments unfortunately.

Comment: Suggest you use the regular calendar table for your slicer. Then you will get the actual date selected. You could then filter your quarterly date table based on the regular date table. Alternatively, I would encourage you use your normal calendar table throughout, and we help you fix your waterfall calculations.

Comment: I changed the date slicer to the original calendar table and used your first measure, and it worked. The waterfall doesn't seem to break any more. I really appreciate your help on this!

Comment: Great, glad to hear it. Please Accept the answer for the benefit of all.